# How to have a layout like this in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I wanna have this layout in Jetpack Compose. How can I place the image at the bottom of the card and have it a bit outside the card borders? Also how to make sure that the content above won't collide with the image, because the content above can be longer. Thanks very much.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Card` for main view layout.

To have an icon placed like this, you need to place it with `Card` into a box, apply `Alignment.BottomCenter` alignment to image and add paddings.

To make image be under your text, I've added `Spacer` with size calculated on image size.

```
@Composable
fun TestView() {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalContentColor provides Color.White
    ) {
        Column {
            LazyRow {
                items(10) {
                    Item()
                }
            }
            Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Color.DarkGray)) {
                Text("next view")
            }
        }

    }
}

@Composable
fun Item() {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .padding(10.dp)
    ) {
        val imagePainter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.test2)
        val imageOffset = 20.dp
        Card(
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(0.dp),
            backgroundColor = Color.DarkGray,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(bottom = imageOffset)
                .width(200.dp)
        ) {
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp)
            ) {
                Text(
                    "Title",
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Start)
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(15.dp))
                Text("PM2.5")
                Text(
                    "10",
                    fontSize = 35.sp,
                )
                Text("m/s")
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(15.dp))
                Text(
                    "Very Good",
                    fontSize = 25.sp,
                )
                Spacer(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(
                            with(LocalDensity.current) { imagePainter.intrinsicSize.height.toDp() - imageOffset }
                        )
                )
            }
        }
        Image(
            painter = imagePainter,
            contentDescription = "",
            Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
        )
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A simple way is to use a `Box` and apply an `Offset` to the `Image`

```
Box() {
    val overlayBoxHeight = 40.dp
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(300.dp)
    ) {
       //...
    }
    Image(
        painterResource(id = R.drawable.xxxx),
        contentDescription = "",
        modifier = Modifier
            .align(BottomCenter)
            .offset(x = 0.dp, y =  overlayBoxHeight )
    )
}
```

[image]

If you want to calculate the offset you can use a `Layout` composable.

Something like:

```
Layout( content = {
    Card(
        elevation = 10.dp,
        modifier = Modifier
            .layoutId("card")
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(300.dp)
    ) {
        //...
    }
    Image(
        painterResource(id = R.drawable.conero),
        contentDescription = "",
        modifier = Modifier
            .layoutId("image")
    )

}){ measurables, incomingConstraints ->

    val constraints = incomingConstraints.copy(minWidth = 0, minHeight = 0)
    val cardPlaceable =
        measurables.find { it.layoutId == "card" }?.measure(constraints)
    val imagePlaceable =
        measurables.find { it.layoutId == "image" }?.measure(constraints)

    //align the icon on the top/end edge
    layout(width = widthOrZero(cardPlaceable),
        height = heightOrZero(cardPlaceable)+ heightOrZero(imagePlaceable)/2){

        cardPlaceable?.placeRelative(0, 0)
        imagePlaceable?.placeRelative(widthOrZero(cardPlaceable)/2 - widthOrZero(imagePlaceable)/2,
            heightOrZero(cardPlaceable) - heightOrZero(imagePlaceable)/2)

    }
}
```